# Logging into a website then clicking a button that redirects to another website

Tags: scrapy

I've looked up basic tutorials on Scrapy but don't have any idea where to start with this. I know that I will have to do a FormRequest of some sort in order to access the main website. From there on, I don't know how to simulate clicking the button so that Scrapy can access the other website. Using the inspect function, it's clear that the button simply redirects to another website, but requires credentials that are not the same as the main website.

I haven't begun any code because I want to lay it all out and plan it from there to see if it is feasible, but am very confused on where to start.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: first start coding.

Comment: You should check all requests, and find how move credential data.